# Syntax error at line 89

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax at line 89 (insert_temp = ...)

I cannot find the syntax error (when commented out, line 92 gives the same error - insert_status = ...).  Can someone please help me out?  I've been looking at this for weeks.

This is the specific portion of the code with the syntax error.

```
# Pass temps & status to db

insert_temp = """INSERT INTO current_temp(DATE_TIME, IN_TEMP, CAR_1_TEMP, CAR_2_TEMP, 
        CAR_3_TEMP) VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d, %d) % (NOW(), i_temp, c_1_temp, c_2_temp, c_3_temp)"""

insert_status = """INSERT INTO 'status' (DATE_TIME, COOL_STATUS, HEAT_1_STATUS,
    HEAT_2_STATUS,IN_FAN_STATUS, CAR_3_FAN) VALUES (NOW(), $c_status,
    $h_1_status, $h_2_status,$i_fan_status, $c_3_fan)"""

try:
   # Execute the insert_temp command
   cursor.execute(insert_temp)
   # Commit your changes in the database
   db.commit()
except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()

try:
   # Execute the insert_status command
   cursor.execute(insert_status)
   # Commit your changes in the database
   db.commit()
except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()
```

The complete file (Py_Ferm_v1.py) can be found at:
[link to GitHub repository](https://github.com/Boombrewer/DrunknFermenter/tree/master/Py_Fermenter)

Its designed to pass information between a MySQL DB and an alamode (arduino).

Comment: Your indentation seems very odd, and your structure could use some functions. That said, please put a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in your question**; put some effort into narrowing it down, so people don't have to traipse all over the internet to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `try` block with no `except` block following it, above that line. This is why you should post the entire code in your question.

Comment: Thank you.  Completely missed looking well above the cited error.